# CLR programming in SQL-Server problem(System.InvalidOperationException: The 'OraOLEDB.Oracle' provider is not registered on the local machine)

Tags: .net, sql-server, oracle, clr

I need to communicate between oracle and mssql. I use CLR in mssql and this exeption :

> A .NET Framework error occurred during
>   execution of user-defined routine or
>   aggregate "Function1":
>   System.InvalidOperationException: The
>   'OraOLEDB.Oracle' provider is not
>   registered on the local machine.
>   System.InvalidOperationException: at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbServicesWrapper.GetDataSource(OleDbConnectionString
>   constr, DataSourceWrapper&
>   datasrcWrapper) at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString
>   constr, OleDbConnection connection) at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection
>   owningObject) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory
>   connectionFactory) at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
>   at UserDefinedFunctions.Function1()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install relevant Oracle drivers

Exactly as it says:

> The 'OraOLEDB.Oracle' provider is not registered on the local machine